# How to structure a website in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple (I hope so) question about the structure of a typical Django website. I have to restructure my site using some "Django-powered" pages mixed to other typical static pages.

I'd like to have a few templates and a lot of pages using these templates.

My question is:

What is the best way to provide different content for each page?
What I'm thinking right now is having different pages in my URL conf using the same templates and modifying the content within the View. But it's so unnatural to "hard-code" my content within the View, I suppose.

Is there a way to define content areas in my template and, for example, edit them within the Admin panel?

There must be better ways, I think.

Thank you!

***Edit***
Maybe Flatpages could help in my task. But does exist a way to add "content areas" tied to specific parts of the templates? I can fine only the main content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generic views, and I would heartily encourage you to. They're great. Check out the [django docs for generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views/). But as for different pages requiring a different template, yeah, that's how websites work.

Django is not "file-light" - it works by combining lots of small files. You're quite right to be averse to hard-coding HTML in your view controller - that's generally bad practice. You're going to have a template for each view, but really, how many views do you have? Even in a large application, the number of views that can't be handled by either a built-in or custom-made generic view is going to be pretty low.

Answer (score 3):

How are your "content areas" different than django's template blocks? You can define something like this in your layout file:

```
base.html
{% block overridable %}Default content{% endblock overridable %}
```

And in your templates, you extend it like this:

```
 view.html
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block overridable %} Overrided by view {% endblock overridable %}
```

Comment: Ok but in this way I have a template for each different page. I want one template to be used for many pages, with content defined within some variables or I don't know what.

Comment: If you know Drupal and its "Blocks" you can understand what I mean.

Comment: This is the purpose of the layout. You define your "variables" there, and override them in the template.

Comment: So, for every page I have a different URL (into urls.py), a different View and a different Template. There is clearly a better way to organize a website.